# Zipping Multiple Lists Together

Tags: python

Say I have multiple lists like:

```
[0,15678,27987,28786]
[1,12456,26789,30006]
[2,15467,29098,24567]
```

How would I go about zipping each entry in each list into a separate list? aka I need to be able to take 0,1,2, etc and put it into a list. Specifically, I want to know if there is an easy way to do this without giving each list a specific name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Comment: What is the result you are expecting to have? a list of lists? or one long list comprised of the members of the shorter lists? Can you specify the result you expect for the example you provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `zip`:

```py
list(zip([0,15678,27987,28786],[1,12456,26789,30006], [2,15467,29098,24567]))
```

From your code, you can collect the data from the reader with:

```py
with open('excelfile.csv','r',newline='') as inp:
    r = csv.reader(inp,delimiter=',')
    my_data = list(r)
```

The just unpack it in `zip`:

```py
list(zip(*my_data))
```

Comment: @JohnSmith, just collecte the lines into a list. Expand your question with all the data so I can update the answer :)

Comment: @JohnSmith consider upvoting and accepting the answer if it was helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip()` with list unpacking

```
x=[[0,15678,27987,28786],
[1,12456,26789,30006],
[2,15467,29098,24567]]

print(list(zip(*x)))

#= Output: [(0, 1, 2), (15678, 12456, 15467), (27987, 26789, 29098), (28786, 30006, 24567)]
```